# How to fix Database Null Exception in ASP.NET-MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

```
services.AddDbContext<StoreContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["Data:StoreProducts:ConnectionString"]));
```

In the appsettings.json:

```
{
"Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Warning"
    }
}
}
```

and in the appsetting.development.json

```
{
"Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Debug",
        "System": "Information",
        "Microsoft": "Information"
    }
},
"Data": {
    "StoreProducts": {
        "ConnectionString": "Server=DESKTOP-I3K90LQ\\SQL2016;Database=BrooksStore;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
    }
}
```

}
I am not sure why services threw me an exception saying options.UseSqlServer has null value in it.
Can anyone help?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value is null because your connection string is in  "appsetting.development.json" not "appsetting.json" so you can put your connection string in appsetting.json and it will work just fine.

**EDIT**

Actually you have a typo in your json file name it's "appsettings.Development.json" not "appsetting.development.json"
notice the 's' 
now it should work correctly from your dev json file